# Specifying Specific Type of a Delegate Argument

Tags: c#

Assuming I have the following delegate

```
public delegate void ControlInitializer(Control control);
```

Is there a way when specifying the delegate to specify what type of control the input parameter is? e.g.

Instead of

```
ControlInitializer one = c => ((TextBox)c).Text = "Init Value"
ControlInitializer two = c => ((DropDownList)c).SelectedValue= "-1"
```

Can I do something like

```
ControlInitializer one = (TextBox c) => c.Text = "Init Value"
ControlInitializer two = (DropDownList c) => c.SelectedValue= "-1"
```

As Textbox is a sub class of Control in this case?

Update: I also need to store these 2 ControlInitialiser delegates in a e.g.

```
Dictionary<string, ControlInitializer>
```

will specifying

```
Dictionary<string, ControlInitializer<Control>>
```

Work in this case as I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use Action<T> instead of defining your own delegate if you're using .NET Framework 3.5.

Comment: `Action<T>` is available in .net 2.0 as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make the delegate generic:

```
public delegate void ControlInitializer<TControl>(TControl control)
    where TControl : Control;
```

And then use it like this:

```
ControlInitializer<TextBox>      one = c => c.Text = "Init Value";
ControlInitializer<DropDownList> two = c => c.SelectedValue = "-1";
```

---

I guess your aiming for something like this:

```
var init = new Init();

init.RegisterInitializer<TextBox>(c => c.Text = "Init Value");
init.RegisterInitializer<DropDownList>(c => c.SelectValue = "-1");

foreach (var c in Controls)
{
    init.ApplyInitializer(c);
}
```

That's a bit difficult due to the reasons mentioned in *David B*'s answer. What you can do, however, is hide the type cast behind an abstraction, like this:

```
public class Init
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<Control>> initializers;
    ...

    public void RegisterInitializer<TControl>(Action<TControl> i)
        where T Control : Control
    {
        initializers.Add(typeof(TControl), c => i((TControl)c));
    }

    public void ApplyInitializer(Control c)
    {
       initializers[c.GetType()](c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds Good.  If I have a Dictionary<string, ControlInitializer> that stores these in a static variable can I initialize it using Dictionary<string, ControlInitializer<Control>> and add delegates "one" and "two"?

Comment: No, because of type covariance

Answer (score 3):

First of all, use the predefined delegate [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx).  As regards specifying the type, use generic arguments:

```
Action<TextBox, string> one = (c,v) => c.Text = v;
```

The `Action` delegate takes up to 4 arguments and doesn't return anything (`void`).

Comment: I realise this but this example is a slight abstraction and Action wouldn;t apply to the real thing.

Comment: then there's always `Predicate` and 3.5's `Func`

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a to a `ControlInitializer<TextBox>` to a dictionary that holds `ControlInitializer<Control>` **because the first type does not inherit from the second type** (even though `TextBox` inherits from `Control`.)  It's all about the lack of Covariance and Contravariance in generics.

You could write your own collection to behave in the way you expect.  Here's one possibility:

```
public class CustomStorage
{
  private Dictionary<string, object> storage = new Dictionary<string, object>();

  public void Remember(string key, object value)
  {
    storage[key] = value;
  }

  public object Retrieve(string key)
  {
    object x = storage[key];
    return x;
  }

  public U Retrieve<U>(string key)
  {
    U u = (U) storage[key];
    return u;
  }
}
```

Which could be used this way:

```
CustomStorage cs = new CustomStorage();
ControlInitializer<TextBox> one = c => c.Text = "Init Value";
ControlInitializer<DropDownList> two = c => c.SelectedValue = "-1";
  //drop the items into the collection ...
cs.remember("TextBox", one);
cs.remember("DropDownList", two);
  // ... and fetch them back
one = cs.Retrieve<ControlInitializer<TextBox>>("TextBox");
two = cs.Retrieve<ControlInitializer<DropDownList>>("DropDownList");
```

Comment: Will it be possible to achieve this in .Net 4.0 which introduces co and contra variances?